# Javascript delete cookie before reload or redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, cookies

I need to delete a cookie and *then* do a redirect.  However the cookie doesn't get deleted until the redirect is processed.  The problem is that if the cookie still exists at the time the redirect is executed, the redirect is intercepted and sent to a page other than the one intended.  (weird, I know; long story)

Is it possible to trick the browser and force the deletion of the cookie before the redirect?

```
jQuery('div#panelD').click(function(){
    document.cookie = 'sharedsession=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; Domain=.example.com; path=/';
    window.location.href = "www.example.com/x";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered if I perform an AJAX call for anything, it qualifies as a refresh for the purposed of deleting cookies.

```
var fakeAjax = new XMLHttpRequest();
var anything = fakeAjax.responseText;
fakeAjax.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",false);  // file doesn't actually exist
fakeAjax.send();
```

Note the "false" in the Open line.  Asynchronous has to be set to false (or some other delay) to allow time for the new info to come back and the cookie to be deleted.

**UPDATE:** IE doesn't like requesting responseText from a file that doesn't exist so just remove that line completely.  Other browsers seem to be fine with or without it.