# Is deleting a cookie in Javascript Synchronous?

Tags: javascript, redirect, cookies

I have more or less a duplicate of [Javascript Delete Cookie Before Reload or Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583250/javascript-delete-cookie-before-reload-or-redirect) which never got any answers.

I inherited some javascript code that does the following

```
 function delete_cookie ( cookie_name )
  {
     var cookie_date = new Date ( );  // current date & time
     cookie_date.setTime ( cookie_date.getTime() - 1 );
     document.cookie = cookie_name += "=; expires=" + cookie_date.toGMTString();
  }
  delete_cookie ( "sessionId" );
  window.location ="https://some_redirect";
```

The problem is that the `GET` for the redirect page contains the original cookie (which apparently was not deleted), and the server just continually responds with the delete/redirect code (tested on chrome/canary/IE).  If it makes a difference, the cookie was initially set to simply "sessionId=;"

The cookie is always set with the following pattern

```
"Set-Cookie: sessionId=%s;path=/;%s postId=%s;%s " "\r\n"
```

I am aware that `toGMTString` is deprecated, and that setting directly to `window.location` is perhaps non-ideal.  Neither of those seem related to the problem.

If I put the `window.location` call inside a `setTimeout`, or if I execute it as a callback from delete_cookie then everything magically works perfectly.  But why?

This *seems* to work reliably

```
function delete_cookie (cookie_name, callback)
{ 
   ...
   callback();
 }
delete_cookie( "sessionID", doRedirect);
```

where `doRedirect` is just the `window.location`

Is this behavior expected?  My presumption was that when the cookie was set with an expiry date in the past it would be deleted before code execution continued. Is there a better mechanism to ensure the cookie has been deleted prior to the redirection?

EDIT: Additional information

Modifying the cookie as follows doesn't help things

```
       function delete_cookie ( cookie_name )
       {
+         var retries = 0;
          var cookie_date = new Date ( );  // current date & time
          cookie_date.setTime ( cookie_date.getTime() - 1 );
          document.cookie = cookie_name += "=; expires=" + cookie_date.toGMTString();
+      
+         while (document.cookie.indexOf("sessionId=") != -1)
+         {
+            retries +=1;
+            if (retries == 1000) 
+            { 
+                console.log("giving up after 1000 retries");
+                break;
+            }
+
+         }
+         console.log("We had to retry "+retries+" time(s)");
       }
       delete_cookie ( "sessionId" );
```

Console output is

> giving up after 1000 retries
>
> We had to retry 1000 time(s)

Interestingly, if I am debugging on the client I see the following

Canary (Version 42.0.2302.2 canary (64-bit))

After the javascript redirect code is served up from the dev console "Resources" tab, under Cookies->10.0.11.118 it says "This site has no cookies."

But in a separate tab to chrome://settings/cookies I can still see

```
Name:   sessionId 
Content:     
Domain: 10.0.11.118 
Path:   / 
Send for:   Any kind of connection 
Accessible to script:   Yes 
Created:    Thursday, February 12, 2015 at 12:26:07 PM 
Expires:    When the browsing session ends
```

Comment: No it's not, setting and deleting cookies is done synchronously.

Comment: However when a cookie has its expiration time changed to some time in the past, the browser will delete this cookie right away, ***BUT ONLY*** when the domain and path attributes in the Set-Cookie field match the values used when the cookie was created. Also, if no path is set, the cookie is only available on the page it was created, to make it available on the entire domain, the path **must** be set to `/`.

Comment: @adeno - the cookie is always set with `path=/;`.  I don't see anything related to domains in any of the code.

Comment: Okay, I didn't see a path being set in the code above, and the deault is not `/` it's the current location, which makes the cookie only available on that page, but if you have a path set in the original code, I guess it's fine.

Comment: Right after you do `delete_cookie()`, read the cookie again and see if it's there before you redirect.  If it is still there, then you aren't deleting it appropriately.  If it is not there, but it is there after redirect, then you must not be doing the path correctly.  Troubleshoot to find out where your error is.

Comment: Also, are you 100% sure the server is not resetting the sessionId when it serves up the redirect page?

Comment: @jfriend00 - the only thing I am remotely sure of is what the server is doing.  It's on an embedded device and I've stepped through it with a debugger.  It's definitely just serving up the javascript snippet without a `Set-Cookie` in the header.  I'm trying with the cookie checks now.

Comment: Sorry to possibly repeat what was previously said, but when you delete the cookie, you need to use the same path you used when you set it. You have `path=/;` when you set the cookie, but no path when you delete it.

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara - I'm new to javascript, I may have misunderstood that part.  Trying now.  Thx

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara - so adding the `path-/;` to the cookie expire logic fixes things, but I can't understand then why `setTimeout` or a callbac would have also fixed things.  It seems like if the path was wrong it should have never worked.

Comment: On my end your `delete_cookie` function didn't work at all without the `path`, perhaps something else was at play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I've tried to make this answer as generic as possible, one of the below issues, either with multiple cookies with the same key, or a not passed enough expiration is your issue*

---

There are several possibilities for cookies not getting deleted.

### You can have more than one of the same cookie

Cookies can be set with several variables.  By setting the same cookie with parameters that do not match, you will create duplicates that your server-side framework may be unable to handle, or default to the first or last one sent to the server.

---

### Cookie Parameters

#### Domain

The domain must be set to the current domain, or parent domain.

#### Path

In addition to a domain hierarchy, there is also a base-path hierarchy.  The default is usually '/', making a cookie available to all paths within the domain.

#### HTTP-ONLY Flag

When set, you will not be able to modify said cookie via JavaScript, and you may well be setting a duplicate cookie if this is the case.

#### Expiration

This doesn't affect duplicates, but if set to an invalid value, or something that isn't far enough back (same second) may be disregarded or create an unexpected cookie.

---

### Suggestions

- Confirm the domain and path that are being set for the cookie in question.
- Use a fixed, known to be old date (`new Date(0).toGMTString()`) instead of adjusting from the current date/time
- ensure that your value being set is empty, conversion from null/undefined may result in an unexpected string.
- use `location.replace('newurl')` instead of assigning the `location.href` to avoid any potential caching issues.

The following should clear your cookie under most circumstances...

`document.cookie = 'YOURKEY=; expires=THU, 01 JAN 1970 00:00:00 GMT';`

If you need to clear a path...

`document.cookie = 'YOURKEY=; expires=THU, 01 JAN 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/';`

#### Aside

In general, don't set your cookies too far into the future...

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with your cookies, but time.

What you are doing is not going a **second** back in time but a **millisecond.**

So when you are asking it for a GMT time format, in most cases it won't even know the difference,  between now and a millisecond ago in time format. It will show the same time as a millisecond ago and the cookie won't be deleted, because the cookie is not yet expired.

What you want to do is to go a thousand milliseconds, thus a second, going back in time.

```
var cookie_date = new Date ( );
alert(cookie_date.toGMTString()); 
//outputs Sat, 14 Feb 2015 18:07:45 GMT

cookie_date.setTime ( cookie_date.getTime() - 1 );
alert(cookie_date.toGMTString()); 
//outputs Sat, 14 Feb 2015 18:07:45 GMT

var good_cookie_date = new Date ( );     
alert(good_cookie_date.toGMTString());
//outputs Sat, 14 Feb 2015 18:07:45 GMT

good_cookie_date.setTime ( good_cookie_date.getTime() - 1000 );
alert(good_cookie_date.toGMTString());
//outputs Sat, 14 Feb 2015 18:07:44 GMT
```

[See fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/10qd3c5h/)

Comment: Interesting.  I won't be able to test this until Tuesday.  Thanks.  -A

Comment: It did not.  I'm wondering if it did fix a concern case that only triggers occasionally, but it seems like the missing "path=/" is the real culprit here.

Answer (score 0):

**Google Chrome**

I tried your code in my machine. I set the cookie with and without path=/. In both cases it is working fine. That is, the code deletes cookie first and then redirects.

**Firefox**

I could reproduce the issue in firefox.

As you told you used path=/ while setting cookie, I used the same format in unsetting.

```
document.cookie = cookie_name += "=; expires=" + cookie_date.toGMTString() + "; path=/";
```

It worked for one time then again showing issue. I could relate the issue with caching. Because when I updated the redirect line to

```
window.location ="redirect.html?"+Math.random();
```

Everything started working smoothly. The random string avoid caching.